# Using DFS Recursively to Find a Particular Path

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, depth-first-search

I am attempting to use DFS to solve a graph problem, and have ran into a wall. This is my implementation in Python3. unvisited is an array of ints, start and end are ints in unvisited, path is an empty array filled out as the DFS goes, and edges is a dictionary of edges.

```
def traverse(unvisited, start, end, path, edges):

copy_unvisited = unvisited.copy()
copy_path = path.copy()
current = start
copy_unvisited.remove(current)
copy_path.append(current)
if current == end and len(copy_unvisited)==0:
    #print is just for me to check my answers
    print(copy_path)
    return copy_path
for i in edges[current]:
    if i in copy_unvisited:
        return traverse(copy_unvisited, i, end, copy_path, edges)
```

The goal is to find a path that starts on start and visits every int in unvisited until ending on end. Therefore, I'm running into a problem with the recursion (I think) because in cases where the path is wrong, I don't want to return anything; instead, I want the DFS to continue. With the way the code is written now, I'm getting "None" returned, even though the correct solution is being printed (because of my print statement). How can I fix this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: If unvisited = [1,3,4,5], start = 4, end = 5, edges = {1: (4,5), 3: (1), 4: (1,3,5), 5: (1,4)},

traverse(unvisited, 4, 5, [], edges) should return [4,3,1,5], but instead I get None. traverse does not have a return type if a wrong path is followed, which is why I think I'm getting None. It eventually finds the right path and prints it.

I have found a solution by introducing a new parameter sol, and when the correct path is reached, I copy each entry of copy_path into sol. Then, I return sol at the END, after the recursive call. I also removed the return statement for the recursive call.

```
def traverse(unvisited, start, end, path, edges,sol):
copy_unvisited = unvisited.copy()
copy_path = path.copy()
current = start
copy_unvisited.remove(current)
copy_path.append(current)
if current == end and len(copy_unvisited)==0:
    for i in copy_path:
        sol.append(i)
for i in edges[current]:
    if i in copy_unvisited:
        traverse(copy_unvisited, i, end, copy_path, edges,sol)
return sol
```

Feels a little inelegant, so I'm open to better ways to solve this problem!

Comment: Can you provide a sample input , the output you get and what you want to get?

Comment: Sure! unvisited = [1,3,4,5], start = 4, end = 5, edges = {1: (4,5), 3: (1), 4: (1,3,5), 5: (1,4)} 
traverse(unvisited, 4, 5, [], edges) should return [4,3,1,5], but instead I get None.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, with the input that you gave, the output should be [4 1 5], since the first edge linked to the vertex 4 is 1 and at the time of the first execution of the DPS 1 still in the unvisited list.

The main problem with your original code is these two instructions:
The

```
len(copy_unvisited)==0:
```

in the first if and the

```
if i in copy_unvisited:
```

at the end.

Basically you have this:

```
First call of the function: 
node 4, unvisited (uv): [1,3,4,5], path=[]
At the for: 4 uv: [1,3,5] edges: (1, 3, 5)
So i=1, i is in uv, then:
Second call of the function:
node 1, uv: [1,3,5], path=[4]
At the for: 1 uv: [3,5] edges: (4,5)
So i=4, but 4 is not in uv,
So i=5, 5 is in uv, then:
Third call of the function *OBS1*
node 5, uv: [3,5], path=[4,1]
it will not enter in the first if, because len(uv) is not equals 0.
At the for: 5 uv: [3] edges: (1,4)
So i=1, but 1 is not in uv
So i=4, but 4 is not in uv
```

The for ends, so the function ends and not call itself, neither return a value.

I am pretty sure the DPS should end when you get in the wanted node, or, when you have no more nodes to visit. In the first case, it should return the path it found, if not, it means the end node there is no path from the start node to the end node (you have it in a disconnected graph).

I tried modify your implementation, but I found it difficult to deal with this "unvisited" variable and with the path being updated in this way. I don't think you are conceptually incorrect, both in the overview of how DFS should work, and in how to update the recurrence, but I was unable to make it work that way and so I modified the algorithm so that it updated the path to as it unstack the functions, instead of doing so while it calls the functions.

```
def traverse(start,end,edges,visited=[],path = []):
    if start == end:
        path.append(start)
        return path
    if start not in visited:
       visited.append(start)
       if start not in edges:
           return path

       for i in edges[start]:

           path = traverse(i,end,edges,visited,path )
           if len(path)>0:
               break

    if len(path)>0 and start not in path:
        path.append(start)
    return path
```

This will return the path, written in reverse, if you want in the normal order just take the final result of the function, which will be a list and apply the .reverse () method on it.

This implementation above is a slight modification of the one I found here: https://likegeeks.com/depth-first-search-in-python/ I just added the part of finding a path between two specific points.

Your "sol" solution work, partially, because, when the DFS get into the the third call and left the for without calling the function again, it, at least can return a empty list, then the third call leaves the stack and the algorithm continues to the next i of the second function call, that is 3. The problem with this implementation is the DFS will read all nodes before return a path to the destination.